# Apex REST response with reserved words

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest

I follow [Creating REST APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)

And I would like to response data as:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "KH001"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

My Class look like this
( everything just work as normal if I used `items` instead of `list` as variable name )
I am wondering would be possible if the response above is really required ?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/kh/*')
global with sharing class RESTKhController {
    @HttpGet
    global static ResponseWrapperClass getList() {
        return new ResponseWrapperClass();
    }

    global class ResponseWrapperClass {
        global List<DataWrapperClass> list; // ERROR unexpected token: 'list'
    }

    global class DataWrapperClass {
        global String id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce Apex and other languages like Java, C etc will give you errors when you try to use reserved words.

However as you said that this response is really required so here is what I suggest.

1. Rename the list to something unique  example: list_replace_me

   ```
   global List<DataWrapperClass> list_replace_me;
   ```
2. Instead of returning the wrapper from your GET method, return a string.

   ```
   global static string getList() { 
   //Manually serialize this object

   new ResponseWrapperClass(); }
   ```
3. Manually serialize the object by `JsonGenerator` class to get a string, or use `JSON.serialize(inputobject)` which return a string.
4. Replace "list_replace_me" with "list" using `String.replace` function.
5. Return the new String after replacing.

[Json Generator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm)

Comment: That a good idea. Seem this is the only way ?

Comment: Yes, this is the one way I can think of. The other way is not to use reserved words.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) with the 'Create explicit parse code' option enabled. This will produce code like so:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class MyList {
    // ...boilerplate...

    public class List_Z {
        public String id {get;set;}

        public List_Z(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'List_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<List_Z> list {get;set;}

    public MyList(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'list') {
                        list = new List<List_Z>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            list.add(new List_Z(parser));
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Root consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...etc...
```

Just replace all occurrences of the `list` member variable with `list_z` (or whatever you like), and you're off to the races:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
// Hand-modified by @metadaddy :-)
//

public class MyList {
    // ...boilerplate...

    public class List_Z {
        public String id {get;set;}

        public List_Z(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'List_Z consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<List_Z> list_z {get;set;}

    public MyList(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'list') {
                        list_z = new List<List_Z>();
                        while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            list_z.add(new List_Z(parser));
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Root consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...etc...
```

Note - you'll also need to move the test code into its own class. Superfell or I need to go back and fix that. We should also rename the member variable when it clashes with a reserved word.

Anyway - now you can create a MyList from JSON like so:

```
MyList l = MyList.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be 6 years too late... but might help someone else...
I was creating a web service for a specific JSON being sent to me (so I do not have the option of changing the names of the values sent to me).  I was able to utilize a class using Map<String,String> to get a generic map of the incoming request.

Specifically, my example:

```
{
    "message": {
        "sms": {
            "from": "12155551212",
            "to": "12155552121"
        },
        "body": "Help"
    }
}
```

I couldn't use "to" or "from" as variable names within my "sms" class... so I implemented this way:

```
global class Message_Incoming { 
    Map<String,String> sms;
    String body;
   
    public Message_Incoming () {
        sms = new Map<String,String>{ 'from' => null, 'to' => null };
    }
}

@HttpPost
global static Message_Response doPost (Message_Incoming message) { ... }
```

It successfully parses the incoming JSON into the class variable, and the "sms" is now a map so I can get the value like this: `message.sms.get('from')`

Comment: Thanks you! :-D

Answer (score -1):

This is 3 years late, but if anyone ever sees this, you can also use `responseString = response.getBody()` and make a string of the response, then use `responseString.Replace('"reservedWord":', '"yourNewWord":')` to map response fields to a wrapper class.

Comment: Hi, just curious I see this post was downvoted. Is replacing string in response bad practice?